# Why is there no embedded c code in arduino libraries?

Tags: library, c

When I took a look at how the arduino libraries were coded I expected to see register names like I/O registers(PINx,DDRx,PORTx) and other such registers with values assigned to them but instead I saw normal C code with functions and a class.

Why isn't there any embedded C in the structure of the library? Am I misunderstanding something very basic? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the Arduino core library (e.g., the AVR version of
[wiring.c](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring.c)), you will see lots of low-level register access. That's
why the core code is specific to a processor architecture.

Other libraries are built on top of the core API in order to be
portable.

Comment: Then why do people even code using low-level registers when they can just use the core API?

Comment: @Roshan: 1. Performance: `digitalWrite()`, for example, is more than 100 times slower than direct port access. 2. Hardware features: the core only provides access to the most generic stuff, you can fully exploit the hardware capabilities only if you access the hardware directly.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Arduino API abstracts those things.

If you put that kind of low-level code into a library the library becomes non-portable.  By sticking to the Arduino API (digitalWrite, pinMode, etc) the library can be used on all boards.